# Angular service data object and primitive values memory location and $digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, primitive, digest

I have a service that holds a data dictionary which has a key `activeBill` that can either have an object as value or be null.

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('shishaModule')
    .service('billsSvc', billsSvc);


  function billsSvc() {
    var self = this;

    self.data = {
        bills: [],
        activeBill: null
    };

    self.selectBill = selectBill;
    self.selectBillByTable = selectBillByTable;
    self.addBill = addBill;
    self.removeBill = removeBill;

    function selectBill (bill){
        /* Selects the recieved Bill if it exists */

        var index = self.data.bills.indexOf(bill);

        if (index != -1){
            self.data.activeBill = self.data.bills[index];
        } else {
            // TODO: Handle Exception: This bill doesn't exist.
        }
    }

    function selectBillByTable(table){
        self.data.bills.forEach(function (bill, index){
            if (bill.owner == table){
                self.selectBill(bill);
            }
        })
    }

    function addBill (bill){
        var index = self.data.bills.indexOf(bill);
        if (index === -1){
            self.data.bills.push(bill);
        } else {
            // TODO: Handle Exception: This bill already exists.
        }

    }

    function removeBill (bill){
        var index = self.data.bills.indexOf(bill);
        if (index != -1){
            self.data.bills.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            // TODO: Handle Exception: This bill doesnt exist.
        }
    }

  }
})();
```

In the controller:

```
vm.billsData = billsSvc.data;

// To set the activeBill equals to a bill
vm.selectBill(<a bill object>);
// To set the activeBill to null
vm.billsData.activeBill = null;
```

Anyway, whenever `activeBill` it's set to `null` further changes to the variable won't be detected by the controller any longer because $digest won't be executed.

I'm not sure what is the issue here, perhaps it's related to the way javascript stores primitive values.

Comment: Can you exactly show us how you are trying to access and manipulate `billsSvc.data` from any controller?

Comment: I edited the question to add the whole process